# django prevent accessing variable before it's defined on submit

Tags: django

I have the following django view that works great except in the instance of clicking the submitted button on the previous view i'm sending the POST information from.

```
def submitted(request):
# sets the employeentname to the username from the POST of results
    owner = ADMirror.objects.get (employeentname=request.POST.get('userpost'))
# sets the firstname of owner
    firstname = owner.employeefirstname
# sets the lastname of owner
    lastname = owner.employeelastname
# gets the POST list for the report_id values in the checkboxes for application names
    checkedlist = request.POST.getlist('report_id')
    reportdetail = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in = checkedlist).values_list('report_name_sc', flat = True).distinct()



# gets the timestamp from the system clock when the submit button is pressed
    access_request_date = timezone.now()
####  Unused at this time, but we can pull the division CFO and facility CFO based on the tables Gregg created in the SQL server database.  We'll let the workflow tool handle this part.
#    facilitycfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = '34222', active = 1, cfo_type = 1).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
#    divisioncfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = '34222', active = 1, cfo_type = 2).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
    #print (facilitycfo)
    #print (divisioncfo)
# gets the access level ie facility, division, market, group, corporate from the results.html POST request sent to submitted.html
    selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid')
# sets access level name and organization level name for the submitted page
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '3':
        accesslevel = 'company-wide access'
        orglevelname = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '4':
        accesslevel = 'group level access'
        accesslevelname = request.POST.getlist('blevel')
        orglevelname = FacilityDimension.objects.filter(b_level__in = accesslevelname).values_list('group_name', flat = True).distinct()
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '5':
        accesslevel = 'division level access'
        accesslevelname = request.POST.getlist('rlevel')
        orglevelname = FacilityDimension.objects.filter(r_level__in = accesslevelname).values_list('division_name', flat = True).distinct()
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '6':
        accesslevel = 'market level access'
        accesslevelname = request.POST.getlist('dlevel')
        orglevelname = FacilityDimension.objects.filter(d_level__in = accesslevelname).values_list('market_name', flat = True).distinct()

    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '7':
        accesslevel = 'facility level access'
        accesslevelname = request.POST.getlist('zcoid')
        orglevelname = FacilityDimension.objects.filter(coid__in = accesslevelname).values_list('coid_name', flat = True).distinct()




# gets the PHI boolean flag from the results.html POST request sent to submitted.html
    selectedphi = request.POST.get('phi')

# if statements to define hte datarduce code based on the selected access level sent from the results.html POST
## corporate
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '3':
        selectlist = "S00001"
# group
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '4':
        selectlist = request.POST.getlist('blevel')
# division
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '5':
        selectlist = request.POST.getlist('rlevel')
# market
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '6':
        selectlist = request.POST.getlist('dlevel')
# facility
    if request.method == 'POST' and selectedaccesslevel == '7':
        selectlist = request.POST.getlist('zcoid')
        selectlist = [f'Z{value}' for value in selectlist]

# nested if/for statement which writes to the [QlikView].[dbo].[QV_FormAccessRequest] table if a corporate access level is selected the datareduce code is set to S00001
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in checkedlist:
            if selectedaccesslevel == '3':
                    requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = 'HCA\\'+owner.employeentname, first_name = owner.employeefirstname, last_name = owner.employeelastname, coid = owner.coid, title = owner.title
                                                    ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi , access_beg_date = access_request_date, previousdatareducecode = '',  datareducecode = 'S00001', facility = owner.facilityname, requestid = '0', requesttype = 'New')# = list(facilitycfo)[0], division_cfo = list(divisioncfo)[0] )
                    requestsave.save()
# part of the nested if/for statement above which writes to [QlikView].[dbo].[QV_FormAccessRequest] if anything other than corporate user is selected it will chose the correct data reduce code based on the select list if statements above.
            else:
                for j in selectlist:
                    requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = 'HCA\\'+owner.employeentname, first_name = owner.employeefirstname, last_name = owner.employeelastname, coid = owner.coid, title = owner.title
                                            ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi , access_beg_date = access_request_date,previousdatareducecode = '', datareducecode = j, facility = owner.facilityname,requestid = '0', requesttype = 'New' )# = list(facilitycfo)[0], division_cfo = list(divisioncfo)[0] )
                    requestsave.save()

    args = {'firstname' : firstname, 'lastname' : lastname, 'owner' : owner, 'accesslevel':accesslevel, 'reportdetail':reportdetail, 'orglevelname':orglevelname}
    return render(request, 'submitted.html', args)
```

I have multiple buttons on my form so I can't use required because it will interfere with the action of another so I am using the following javascript validation.

```
function submitFormSub(action) {
  var form = document.getElementById('form1');
  form.action = action;
  var accesslevelid = document.getElementById('accesslevelid');
  if (form.action == 'submitted')
  {
    if ($('#accesslevelid').val() == "")
  {
      alert('Please select an access level');
      return false;
    }

    form.submit();
  }

}
```

The validation above works wonderful, as i see the alert, but the form still tries to submit and I'm greeted with the following error.

```
local variable 'accesslevel' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options:

1) Convert your form to a Django `Form` so that you can override the validation methods and thus have it kick back the form when its `is_valid` method is called and fails. That is almost certainly the cleanest. You could also define the different choices using the `choices` keywords on fields and clean up a LOT of unnecessary code.

2) Call `selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid', None)` and on `None` skip to rendering a return without the logic of trying to set an access level and not processing the form to create `QVFormAccessRequest` instances.

To explain:

```
selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid', None)
if selectedaccesslevel:
   # all your code that defines and sets access levels that you
   # don't want to run because it doesn't have a crucial bit of info
args = {'firstname' : firstname, 'lastname' : lastname, 'owner' : owner, 'accesslevel':accesslevel, 'reportdetail':reportdetail, 'orglevelname':orglevelname}
return render(request, 'submitted.html', args)
```

Comment: I had issues using the Django Forms based on the requirements of moving data through several forms, so I can't go that route.  Where would I skip to returning a return without the logic?

Comment: Worked great for me, but now how can I get it to return the original view instead of getting this error:  The view mysite.search.views.submitted didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I'd check your indentation and logic flow. You're hitting a situation where you don't `return render`.